# Jquery with 2 clicks functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I want to select or deselect a div with a click.

I want this :

- click 1 = add color and select div
- click 2 = if is the same id go pink, if different go white.

My problem is when I click on the first div (go red), then the second div (first go white and second too), then the third div, the third div go pink, or I want re run the script (for make the third div red like the first div).

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $i = 1;
    $firstcase = "";

    $(".blackcase").click(function firstclick(event) {

        if ($i == 1) 
        {
            $("#" + event.target.id).css("background-color", "red");
            $firstvalue = $("\#" + event.target.id).html();
            $firstcase = "\#" + event.target.id + "";
            $i++;
        }         
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }

        $(".blackcase").one("click", function (event) {

            $firstcase2 = "\#" + event.target.id + "";

            if ($("#" + event.target.id).is($firstcase)) 
            {
                $("#" + event.target.id).css("background-color", "pink");
                $i = 0;
                $firstcase = "";
                return;
            }             
            else 
            {
                $(".blackcase").css("background-color", "white");
                $i = 1;
                $firstcase = "";
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/12gwq95u/3/

Comment: A: variables in javascript are declared with `var [variable_name]` and don't need the `$` prefix. B: you assign a `$firstcase2` variable (i think by mistake) and never use it.

Comment: Thanks, yes the $firstcase2 a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can massively simplify your logic if you have a single event handler and store the last clicked id in a variable outside of the click handler. Try this:

```
var lastClicked = '';
$(".blackcase").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.blackcase').removeClass('red pink');
    $(this).addClass(lastClicked != this.id ? 'red' : 'pink');
    lastClicked = this.id;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/12gwq95u/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's more logic ! Can you explain me why you have put "e.preventDefault()" ?  Thanks

Comment: `preventDefault()` stops the normal event behaviour. It is similar to the `return false;` you originally had, except it doesn't prevent the event bubbling up the DOM. You could remove it if you preferred, as a `div` element doesn't raise a cancellable event.

Comment: More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: If you can help me for this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450763/jquery-swap-two-value-and-change-style/33455601#33455601                                                                                 Thanks !