# Jquery : swap two value and change style

Tags: javascript, jquery, swap

i need to make a script for select a black div by click(go red), and put black div value into a white div value by another click, this is ok but when i try to swap values of two white case, the change do correctly one time, but if i retry to swap two value of white case the values swap correctly but whitout the background color red.

This is my code :

```
var lastClicked = '';
var lastClicked2 = '';

$(".blackcase").click(function(e) {
    var i = 0;
    if ($(this).html().length == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.blackcase').removeClass('red');

        if (lastClicked != this.id) {
            $(this).addClass('red');
            var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
            var currentVal = $(this).html();

            $(".whitecase").click(function(e) {
                $('.blackcase').removeClass('red');
                var currentId2 = $(this).attr('id');

                if (i <= 0 && $("#" + currentId2).html().length == 0) {
                    $("#" + currentId2).html(currentVal);
                    $("#" + currentId).html("");
                    i = 1;
                }
            });
        } else {
            lastClicked = this.id;
        }
    }
});

$(".whitecase").click(function(e) {
    var j = 0;
    if ($(this).html().length == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.whitecase').removeClass('red');

        if (lastClicked2 != this.id) {
            $(this).addClass('red');
            var currentId0 = $(this).attr('id');
            var currentVal0 = $(this).html();

            $(".whitecase").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var currentId02 = $(this).attr('id');
                var currentVal02 = $(this).html();

                if (j <= 0 && currentVal0 != currentVal02) {
                    $('.whitecase').removeClass('red');
                    $("#" + currentId02).html(currentVal0);
                    $("#" + currentId0).html(currentVal02);
                    j = 1;

                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            lastClicked2 = this.id;
        }
    }
});
```

This is JSfiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/12gwq95u/12/

Try to take 12 and put into first white case, put 39 into second white case, click on the white case with 12 (go red) then click on the white case with 39, the values swap correctly with the red color when it's select, but if you try to reswap two whitecase values thats work but without the red color.

Thanks a lot

Comment: if i click 12 and click on white case it does change the value but after that even if i click 39 and click on white div it put 12 in white div not 39

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe you have click on 12 after move 12 on white case before cliqued on 39 on blackcase.  I need to solve that to, i need to capture value when the first div is selected ( and go red), and after put the value with the other click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spent some time to rewrite your code to make it more clear. I don't know what exactly your code should do but according to the information you have already provided, my version of your code is the following:

```
var selectedCase = {color: "", id: ""};

function removeSelectionWithRed() {
   $('div').removeClass('red'); 
}

function selectWithRed(element) {
    removeSelectionWithRed();
    element.addClass('red');
}

function updateSelectedCase(color, id) {
    selectedCase.color = color;
    selectedCase.id = id;
}

function moveValueFromTo(elemFrom, elemTo) {
    elemTo.html(elemFrom.html());
    setValueToElem("", elemFrom);
}

function setValueToElem(value, elem) {
    elem.html(value);
}

function swapValuesFromTo(elemFrom, elemTo) {
    var fromValue = elemFrom.html();
    var toValue = elemTo.html();
    setValueToElem(fromValue, elemTo);
    setValueToElem(toValue, elemFrom);
}

function isSelected(color) {
    return selectedCase.color == color;
}

function clearSelectedCase() {
    selectedCase.color = "";
    selectedCase.id = "";
}

function elemIsEmpty(elem) {
   return elem.html().length == 0;
}

$(".blackcase").click(function (e) {
    if (elemIsEmpty($(this))) {
        return;
    }

    alert("black is selected");
    selectWithRed($(this));
    updateSelectedCase("black", $(this).attr("id"), $(this).html());
});

$(".whitecase").click(function (e) {    
    removeSelectionWithRed();

    if (isSelected("black")) {
        alert("moving black to white");

        moveValueFromTo($("#"+selectedCase.id), $(this));

        clearSelectedCase();
        return;
    }

    if(isSelected("white") && selectedCase.id !== $(this).attr("id")) {
        alert("swap whitecase values");

        swapValuesFromTo($("#"+selectedCase.id), $(this));

        clearSelectedCase();
        return;
    }

    alert("white is selected");
    selectWithRed($(this));
    updateSelectedCase("white", $(this).attr("id"), $(this).html());
});
```

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/12gwq95u/21/

If my answers were helpful, please up them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's more clean like this !

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have multiple $(".whitecase").click() handlers and they don't override each other but instead they all execute in the order in which they were bound.

I advise you to debug your code in browser console by setting breakpoints in every click() event you have (in browser console you can find your file by navigating to the Sources tab and then (index) file in the first folder in fiddle.jshell.net).

In general I think you should rewrite you code in such a way that you won't have multiple handlers to the same events and you can be absolutely sure what your code does.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain more about "setting breakpoints in every click() event you have (in browser console you can find your file by navigating to the Sources tab and then (index) file in the first folder in fiddle.jshell.net)." ?

Comment: Basically you need to debug your code, you can do it by opening your file in browser and setting breakpoints. For more information read this post https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging. Debugging will help you to understand how your code actually works and will point your errors as well.